# Jquery global array variable and dynamically created button issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have global array variable so i can access it from many functions. Problem occurs when im trying to use this variable in function that is bind to button created dynamically, variable is undefined then.

> var  array = [[]];

```
  $('#edit').on("click", "input[id='button']", function(){
```

... i can't use this variable here and i wanna to put some values:- array[index1][index2]=...

```
});
```

I even made function to get this array and assign to new variable, and i can get values that was already in this array, but i can't add new ones cause of error "can't convert undefined to object". **What seems to be the problem, and how to solve that ?
Maybe some workaround ?**

Comment: `"input[id='button']"` = `#button`

Comment: I don't have problem with selector :>

Comment: I know - it was merely a suggestion.

Comment: Thx,i know this, but i use a lot with "^=" so i went for longer version ;d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure your indexes are correct? On the initialization you are creating an empty array at `array[0]`, so the first added value would be at `array[1]`. The inner brackets are not necessary for a multidimensional array, it's just `var array = [];` unless you wanted to initialize an empty array at index 0. Also when you're assigning the value, make sure the second dimension of the array is initialized:

```
var array = [[]];    // creates an empty array at index 0, so we'll add at 1
array[1][0] = 'foo'; // won't work since array is not initialized
array[1] = []; 
array[1][0] = 'bar'; // works
```

If that doesn't help try posting more code, like how your indexes are generated.

Comment: Yeah that helped. I still can't reach that global variable, but my workaround now works.You were right, problem was with initializing second dimension for higher index of array. Thanks.